# How to schedule a job as specific user

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

In my requirement i have to send the custom report developed by us through email. So i have created apex scheduler class,email template and visualforce component.

But when i schedule the job...there is no option to change the submitted by user it is taking my name in the submitted by.Because of this in mail instead of user name in From address my name is appearing.

If i login as that specific user...that user cant see the schedule job in his org.

How i can change the submitted by...i am working on scheduler for the first time so please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not easy way to proxy as other users in salesfoec and the is by design. Its designed that way to that auditing shows the right information.

There are 2 workarounds for you.

1. Other user need to give you "login as" permission and then you can login on that users behalf and submit the job
2. You can create UI using apex and VF and ask user to click on button and then in controller schedule the job. This will set the submitted by as other user.